# Search R file by package used

Tags: r

Let's say I open R file that I used way back when. On top of the page I see a library loaded, but I don't remember what it does any more. So I think to myself: hm, I wonder where in this long R file is this library used?

Is there a way to list what functions from a given package were used in particula file?

Comment: Right, I can use help(package=target) and list all of the functions, and then CTRL + F one by one. But if there are many functions, that can take a long time. I was hoping there is a way to do this automatically. [edit: here I was responding to now deleted comment, but I'll leave it for clarification)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are certainly other ways to do this but if you can get a list of the functions for the package you could combine `readLines` (to read the script into R as characters), `grepl` (to detect matches), and `sapply`.  The way I would grab the functions is using `p_funs` from the [pacman](https://github.com/trinker/pacman) package.  (Full disclosure: I am one of the authors).

Here is an example script that I have saved as "test.R"

```
library(ggplot2)

x <- rnorm(20)
y <- rnorm(20)
qplot(x, y)

summary(x)
```

and here is a session where I detect which functions are used

```
script <- readLines("test.R")
funs <- p_funs(ggplot2)
out <- sapply(funs, function(input){any(grepl(input, x = script))})
funs[out]
#[1] "ggplot" "qplot"
```

If you don't want to install pacman you can use any other method to get a list of the functions in the package.  You could replace that with

```
funs <- objects("package:ggplot2")
```

and you would essentially get the same answer.

Note that you may get more matches than there actually are in the file - note that the ggplot function wasn't actually in my script but the string "ggplot" is in `library(ggplot2)`.  So you may still need to do a little bit of additional digging after the initial sweep through the file.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I hope this isn't inappropriate place to ask: Why is pacman not on CRAN?

Comment: Mainly because there are still a few bugs I know about (that aren't necessarily minor) that I want to work out before uploading.  Tyler and I had plans to release in February but we've both been quite busy and work on pacman has slowed.  With the semester coming to a close soon I'm hoping we'll be able to get it on CRAN fairly soon.

Comment: @user1754606 Just submitted pacman to CRAN.  Should be available in a few days.